# Update table values after event PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have window that contains a table which is populated by a sqllite db.
Upon selecting a row within the table I would like to delete the db row display a confirmation pop up and refresh the table to reflect.
The process of selecting the row, returning vals, updating db & displaying the pop up works... however i cannot get the table to reflect the change and getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ryan/VT_Projects/record_collection_gui/input_tab.py", line 152, in <module>
    row_index = values["-RECORDSTABLE-"][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

[image]

Delete function and main loop:

```
def delete_record(selected_row: list) -> None:
    db.delete_db_item(table="records_data", key=selected_row[0])
    sg.popup(f"Deleted {selected_row[1]} {selected_row[2]}", title="Delete successful")


def edit_record(selected_row: list, evnt, val) -> None:
    pass


window = sg.Window("Vinyl Catalogue", table_layout, modal=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == "-RECORDSTABLE-":
        row_index = values["-RECORDSTABLE-"][0]
        selected_row_values = table_array[row_index]
    else:
        pass

    if event == "-DELETERECORD-":
        try:
            delete_record(selected_row_values)
            window["-RECORDSTABLE-"].update(values=table_array)
        except NameError:
            sg.popup_error("Please select row to delete", title="Error")

    elif event == "-EXPORTCSV":
        export_csv(table_array)
    
    elif event == "-QUIT-":
        break

window.close()
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe it is caused by no selection in your table, so value for `values["-RECORDSTABLE-"]` is `[]`, that's why you got `IndexError: list index out of range`. One `if` statement to check the value of `values["-RECORDSTABLE-"]` before you call `values["-RECORDSTABLE-"][0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Handled `IndexError` caused by missing value after deletion.
Used `refresh()` to update values within table post deletion.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from database import db_querys as db

def delete_record(table: list, row: list, index: int) -> None:
    db.delete_db_item(table="records_data", key=row[0])
    del table[index]


window = sg.Window("Vinyl Catalogue", table_layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == "-RECORDSTABLE-":
        try:
            row_index = values["-RECORDSTABLE-"][0]
            selected_row = table_array[row_index]
        except IndexError:
            continue

    if event == "-DELETERECORD-":
        try:
            delete_record(table_array, selected_row, row_index)
            window['-RECORDSTABLE-'].update(table_array)
            sg.popup(f"Deleted {selected_row[1]} {selected_row[2]}", title="Delete successful")
        except NameError:
            sg.popup_error("Please select row to delete", title="Error")


    elif event == "-EXPORTCSV":
        export_csv(table_array)

    elif event == "-QUIT-":
        break

window.close()
```